# Can you destructure a JavaScript Object in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojurescript

I was wondering if there was a way to get ClojureScript destructuring to work with JavaScript objects, such as:

```
(let [{:keys [a b]} #js{:a 10, :b 20}]
  (print a)  ;=> I get nil, but I'd want to get 10
  (print b)) ;=> I get nil, bu I'd want to get 20
```

Thank You

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Associative destructuring is based on `get`, which can be mapped onto `goog.object/get` for JavaScript objects by extending them to `ILookup`:

```
(extend-type object
  ILookup
  (-lookup 
   ([o k] 
     (goog.object/get o (name k)))
   ([o k not-found] 
     (goog.object/get o (name k) not-found))))
```

Even though this results in destructuring working on JavaScript objects, it isn't advisable to extend `object` in this way. It would be preferable to decorate an object instance to achieve a similar effect.

Here is an example using `reify`:

```
(defn wrap [o]
  (reify
    ILookup
    (-lookup [_ k]
      (goog.object/get o (name k)))
    (-lookup [_ k not-found]
      (goog.object/get o (name k) not-found))))
```

With `wrap` as defined above:

```
(let [{:keys [a b]} (wrap #js{:a 10, :b 20})]
  (print a)
  (print b))
```

Functions in libraries that offer a capability like `wrap` above include:

- `lookup` in [js-interop](https://github.com/appliedsciencestudio/js-interop)
- `bean` in [CLJS Bean](https://github.com/mfikes/cljs-bean)

Comment: I'm now curious, what's the rationale for the advice against extending objects as such?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found a direct way to destructure JS object. You can convert JavaScript object to a ClojureScript datastructure and then destructure:

```
(let [{:keys [a b]} (js->clj #js {:a 10 :b 20}
                             :keywordize-keys true)]
  (print a)
  (print b))
```

If you don't use `:keywordize-keys` option in `js->clj` you need to use `strs` instead of `keys` in the destructuring

```
(let [{:strs [a b]} (js->clj #js {:a 10 :b 20})]
  (print a)
  (print b))
```

Answer (score 2):

Matt Huebert's [js-interop](https://github.com/applied-science/js-interop) library provides [JavaScript object destructuring](https://github.com/applied-science/js-interop#destructuring) out of the box with its version of `let`. All you have to do is add `^:js` in front of the binding form:

```clj
(ns foo.bar
  (:require [applied-science.js-interop :as j]))

(j/let [^:js {:keys [a b]} #js{:a 10, :b 20}]
  [a b])
;; => [10 20]
```

This applies recursively (there's an escape hatch, `^:clj`) and works in `j/fn` and `j/defn` as well. These functions act like normal Clojure if the `^:js` is left out.